# A clause in my employment contract is impossible to fulfill due to covid 19. Does this render the other bindings invalid?

Tags: contract-law, employment, breach-of-contract

Without revealing exactly what clause in my employment contract is now impossible to fulfill, does anyone know what kind of implication it has on the rest of my contract? Is my entire contract null and void as I can no longer possibly abide by the thing in its entire?

Details: I physically can not do what I am supposed to do as set out in my contract due to the effects of a nationwide Covid-19 lockdown. 90% of my colleagues are currently in the same position and breaking this clause too.

Shouldn't my company revise all of our contracts to bring it to speed with the current climate? I feel like we're all liable to being fired as we're all in breach.

I'm interested in this because I've begun doing something else forbidden by the terms as a direct result of my situation/Covid. I know there's a difference between choosing to break a contract and being forced to break one by the pandemic. But do you think I will be as severely punished as would've been the case under "normal" circumstances?

Looking forward to seeing your opinions!

Comment: Your employer can’t legally ask you to do something illegal. So if something is illegal and you don’t do it, you are not in breach of your employment contract. If it was legal when the contract was signed and suddenly becomes illegal that is unfortunate for your employer but doesn’t make a difference.

Comment: Your employer most likely doesn’t need to change the contract, assuming that whatever is illegal now due to COVID will become legal again in the future.

Comment: Read your contract completely.  Almost all employment reated contracts have a specific paragraph that states if one clause is voided (for whatever reason) the others still hold and are unaffected